# How to participate in the Spring Applicaiton Context Initialization Lifecycle?

Tags: spring

How do I hook into the initialization of the Spring Application Context, in a way that allows my code to halt the initialization?

I want to write code which executes after all the beans are fully initialized but before Spring fires ContextRefreshedEvent with the ability to halt the initialization if my code fails to do what it needs to do.

In particular I want to start Quartz Schedule but only after everything has started and if quartz fails to start I want to stop the application. Currently I am using a Servlet context listener like this one to accomplish the task.

```
public class QuartzServletContextListener implements ServletContextListener
{

    @Override
    public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {
        ServletContext servletContext = sce.getServletContext();
        WebApplicationContext applicationContext = WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(servletContext);
        Scheduler scheduler = applicationContext.getBean(Scheduler.class);
        try
        {
            scheduler.start();
        } catch (SchedulerException e)
        {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent sce)
    {

    }
}
```

The servlet context listener runs after the spring context loader listener and the RuntimeException stops tomcat.

Comment: Throwing a `RuntimeException` in an `InitializingBean` or a `BeanPostProcessor` would certainly halt initialization, but what do you want to do in that scenario? Is it recoverable?

Comment: @superEb I want to start the Quartz scheduler manually, but only after everything is ready to go and if the Quartz Scheduler fails to start I want the application to fail on start-up. I have explicitly configured the spring quartz factory bean with auto start to false.

Comment: Sounds like `BeanPostProcessor#postProcessAfterInitialization` is the hook you're looking for. Just define a bean that implements this, and it will automatically be discovered and invoked for every bean initialized in the `ApplicationContext`. That will give you a chance to inspect whatever conditions you're looking for before manually starting your Quartz scheduler.